# Property of continuous functions regarding maximum

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Claim 1: If $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f$ assumes a maximum value

I know there's a theorem that states if $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on a closed interval $[a, b]$, then $f$ is a bounded function. And $f$ assumes its max and min values on $[a, b]$.

Going back to the claim, it doesn't state that $f$ is necessarily bounded. (I understood it as $x$ are bounded, i.e., $a \leq x \leq b$, but $f(x)$ is not necessarily bounded? Since $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, for $a \leq x \leq b$). So I think it is false. And my counterexample is $f(x) = tan(x)$ where $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Although $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, it is not bounded, so it does not assume a maximum value. Is my logic correct?

Claim 2: If $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ assumes a maximum, then $f$ is continuous.

I feel like this is not necessarily true, either? Since a function might have a jump discontinuity and that point might be the max, but the function is not continuous. Would this be correct?

Comment: Your $f$ is not continuous, nor even defined, on all of $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: $f(x) = \tan x$ is not continuous at $x = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ and claim 2 as you point out is not necessarily true, $f$ can have discontinuity at a point and still have maxima and minima in its domain of definition.

Comment: I see. So claim 1 is true then?

Comment: Claim 1 is true. Claim 2 clearly not. Just take indicator functions to get a counter example. By the way: A continuous function on a compact interval, as $[a,b]$ is, must also be bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim 1 is the [Extreme value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) by Weierstrass.

Claim 2 is false.

Easy example:

$$ f [0,1] \to  \mathbb{R} , f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x & x \neq 1 \\ 
10 & x=1 \\ 
\end{cases}  $$

has a maximum ( $\max(f)=10$ ), but is not continous in $x=1$